# Grid - Flex Responsive css section based on columns count and min width

Tags: html, css, sass

**I've nodejs panel that allow user to add section and let the user add the following properties to that section:-**

1- **Columns count** for the section

2- **Minimum column width** for all columns

**e.g -- column count = 4 | minimum column width = 180px**

**Test cases:-**

- If the **user screen is 1920px** it will **display all the columns** in **one row** and stretch the width of the column to more than 180px to fill the section space (1920px).
- If the **user screen is 480px** it will **display only 2 columns** in **each row** and stretch the width of the column to more than 180px to fill the section space (480px).

I tried

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(min(260px,25%),1fr));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the use case is here without further information which also makes it hard to answer your question. It seems like you are giving users the ability to add content of some type to a section though.

On that basis I would suggest the column count is unlikely to be something you need to add to your CSS and would instead be dictated by the number of child elements (grid items) inside your grid container. In your example that would mean when the user chose "column count 4", four children should be created inside your grid container.

Your CSS should be used to tell the browser how to handle the grid items inside your grid container. That is where the user input "minimum column width = 180px" comes in.

Your HTML – based on the user input of "column count 4" – would look like this (I'm using BEM syntax for class names):

```
<section class="user-grid">
   <div class="user-grid__item user-grid__item--1"></div>
   <div class="user-grid__item user-grid__item--2"></div>
   <div class="user-grid__item user-grid__item--3"></div>
   <div class="user-grid__item user-grid__item--4"></div>
</section>
```

As you want to set your minimum column widths dynamically you could use a component-scoped CSS variable and edit that as required. You may wish to do it another way of course. The key line that you're after below is just the `grid-template-columns` property. CSS (in SCSS form) is as follows:

```
.user-grid {
  --min-column-width: 180px; // the value here is what you would change based on the user setting

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(var(--min-column-width), 1fr)); // this is the key line

  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 100px;

  &__item {
    height: 100px;
    
    &--1 {
      background: darkred;
    }

    &--2 {
      background: cadetblue;
    }
    &--3 {
      background: yellowgreen;
    }

    &--4 {
      background: pink;
    }
  }
}
```

The HTML and the CSS combined will mean that screens >=720px wide (i.e. 180px * 4) will always have four equal sized columns and below that they will wrap as required and your test cases will pass.

You are basically telling the browser, "Put my HTML into columns. All the columns together should always take up the full width of the screen. Each column should be at least 180px wide. The only exception is if the screen is smaller than 180px wide in which case just make each column take up all the available width."

You can [check out a codepen here](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/NWYmKZG)